# error: No database selected

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to retrieve data from mysql database, it gives me an error "**No database selected**" This is query:

```
$safe_brand_drug_name = strtoupper($drug_name);
$query = "SELECT * FROM brand_drug where brand_drug_name = {$safe_brand_drug_name}";
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<h1>User result</h1>";

if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['brand_drug_name'] ." - " .$row["manufacturers"] . " - " . $row["type"] . " - " . $row["price"];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

and this is my db connection:

```
define("DB_SERVER", 'localhost');
define("DB_USER", 'root');
define("DB_PASS", '1234');
define("DB_NAME", 'brand_generic');
```

`brand_generic` is my db name.

Comment: Well, I would say some of your database credentials is wrong. Your user / password is correct?

Comment: Are you opening a connection? The db connection you've posted is just a series of credentials being defined.

Comment: Your "db connection" is not a connection - it's just variable definitions

Comment: You need `mysql_select_db` or `mysqli_select_db` to select database. You seem to have both `mysql` and `mysqli` functions in your code sample, you should correct that.

Comment: I would suggest sticking with `mysqli`, in addition to previous comment of @IgorJerosimić.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code's failure to properly execute is, you are mixing MySQL APIs using `mysql_query($query)` `mysql_error()` along with `mysqli_fetch_array()`

They do **not** mix together, being `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions.

Change it to `mysqli_query($con,$query)` (passing DB connection variable first, then the query) while using:

`or die(mysqli_error($con))` instead of `mysql_error()`.

and

```
$DB_SERVER = "localhost";
$DB_USER = "root";
$DB_PASS = "1234";
$DB_NAME = "brand_generic";
```

in conjunction with:

```
$con = new mysqli($DB_SERVER, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($con->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $con->connect_error . ']');
}
```

***or,*** as you have it using `define`, defining them as constants:

```
define("DB_SERVER", 'localhost');
define("DB_USER", 'root');
define("DB_PASS", '1234');
define("DB_NAME", 'brand_generic');

$con = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if($con->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $con->connect_error . ']');
}
```

Since there isn't a variable to stitch it all together as shown above `$con = ...`, then MySQL/PHP doesn't know what to fetch as part of being the connection code. Constants alone without the whole being assigned to a variable, cannot distinguish what it is to use.

Also, make sure there are no other instances of `mysql_` in the rest of your code, should there be any.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) immediately following your opening `<?php` tag.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` which will signal any errors found.

---

***Sidenote:***

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

Do use [**`mysqli_` prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) - *it's safer.*

Answer (score -1):

Try to use database "`brand_generic`" in the Query in following way:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM brand_generic.brand_drug where brand_drug_name = {$safe_brand_drug_name}";
```

Hopefully it will solve the issue.